# Making unordered list slide with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, carousel

JSFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/Vd8PJ/1/

Basically what I'm trying to do here is make the unordered list containing the images slide to the right. My plan is to bring the images that go out of the frame to the back of the line using .before and then putting this slide on an endless loop, producing a carousel. However, I cannot even get the unordered list to slide. What have I done wrong here?

I'm trying to produce the sliding motion with...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$(".gallery-container").animate({"margin-left":"250px"} 3000);

});
```

The list has a margin of -940 pixels, so this should bring it to the right.

Comment: Does it have a `position` definition in the CSS?

Comment: Yep. Its in the JSFiddle. Positioning is relative.

Comment: I missed the comma. Duh. Thanks...

Comment: your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/5wn4L/ but there should be a comma between `{"margin-left":"250px"}` and `3000`